# How do I decrease Google form size?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-apps-script

Is there any way to change the size on google form, for example through JavaScript? I would like to make the form not to long.

Thank you, 
Buzz

Comment: What code have you got so far?

Comment: I don't have any code yet. Just have got google form so far.

Comment: And what is this mighty google form you are talking about? Is it written without any code?

Comment: MauriceNino, I mean just standard google forms like this one  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfgbTBuiCZqX0qIqDoV6IvS9IQcVi04qBf7oc_LDYLb0k78eQ/viewform?c=0&w=1  I've already got one but I'd like to resize of site in order to decrease length.